# how to align <i> side by side with <h5>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to use a font-awesome icon as a bullet point but the h5-tag starts under the fa-icon instead of being on the same line.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="font-size:30px"></i>
        <h5>100% Guaranteed Chargeback</h5>
```

Comment: Why not just put the `<i>` inside the `<h5>`? E.g. `<h5><i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="font-size:30px"></i>100% Guaranteed Chargeback</h5>`

Comment: `span` cannot contain block level elements such as headings.

Comment: @j08691 it worked, thanks. Imagine what i'd been struggling with had so simple a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can align variable-height elements using `display: flex` and `align-items: center`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container i {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="container">
  <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="font-size:30px"></i>
  <h5>100% Guaranteed Chargeback</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option to add it via a pseudo element.

```css
.check-circle::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", sans-serif;
  content: ' \f058 ';
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">


<h5 class="check-circle">100% Guaranteed Chargeback</h5>
```

unicode value can be found on fontAwesome site at description's icon : https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/check-circle